# [SHELL SCRIPTING SMALL PROJECT]

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

I am currently trying to complete this shell script for a small project I have for my class. I'm lost as to how to go about this problem. Here is the prompt and what I have so far...

[image: The initial prompt given]

What I have so far...

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1="-f" ]
then
        Filename=$1
        shift
        shift
elif=[ $1="-a" ]
then
        Adding=$1
        shift
then
fi
```

Comment: first hint, your elif should just be an independent if statement, unrelated to the prior if, because you want to see if $1 is -a in both the case where -f was provided, and in the case it was not. same with -n. second hint, think about why your script runs shift twice after reading -f from $1.  if I called `script.sh -f myFilename`  then $1 is -f, but how do I grab the argument "myfilename" in order to set it to a variable in the script? make those fixes and then edit your post to contain the updated version.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618). The link leads to our sister site but the reasoning is equally valid here. [Edit] and post text instead.

Comment: Use getopts in the script. For an example see: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash>

Answer (score -1):

The easiest is to use getopts.

An example can be found here:
[An example of how to use getopts in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash)

Cheers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please note that the assignment instructions specifically dictate the use of positional arguments and the shift command, so while in the real world, I too recommend getopts, it is inappropriate in this circumstance.